# Pandas apply method: get an index label from a pivot_table

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, pivot-table, apply

I am using a well-known dataset as an example. These are the most popular baby names given to a newborn baby in New York City, based on ethnicity. This well-known dataset is available at this address:"https://data.cityofnewyork.us/api/views/25th-nujf/rows.csv"

I have been using Pandas for a few months, and still have issues with the pivot_table.
I wanted to know for each year, what is the most popular first name, and I did this (it works):

```
import pandas as pd
url = "https://data.cityofnewyork.us/api/views/25th-nujf/rows.csv"
df = pd.read_csv (url)
pt = df.pivot_table (index = "Child's First Name", columns = "Year of Birth", values ​​= "Gender", aggfunc = "count", fill_value = 0, margins = True)
```

The variable pt gives me the list of first names, in line, and in column the years. And the values ​​are the number of times the first name has been given for a year.

Now, I want to do the opposite: from a value over one year, find the corresponding index (therefore the first name).
For example, I want to know which first names were given 4 times in 2015.
To do this I do:

```
condition = pt [2015] == 4
result = pt [condition]
print(result)
```

Now I will want to use an apply function which will return me for each row, the first name in question.
I did this, **but it doesn't work**:

```
pt ["First Name First Letter"] = pt.apply (lambda x: x.index [0], axis = 1)
```

I definitely want to use the apply function because I feel that there is always something that works differently when dealing with a pivot_table...
Who could help me please ?
[Here is the false result I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBjYK.png)

Comment: still no answer ?

Comment: In your example, you're using the `.apply()` call on the whole unfiltered dataframe (`pt`) - not the filtered dataframe (`result`). Can you provide an example of the dataframe you want to get?